# Using web request to fetch and show strings in client side

Tags: c#, webforms, httpwebrequest

So with the below code I managed to fetch the strings that are in a 3rd party website and using table I am displaying it on the client side of my project. But the problem is that each letters are separated on all the strings as shown in the below picture.

[image]

The below would be the code I use,

```
public void Main()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
          "http://www.example.com");
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        var responseList = responseFromServer.Split('\n').ToList();
        var remaining = sqlList.Where(x => !responseList.Contains(x)).ToList();   
        var remaining1 = responseList.Where(x => !sqlList.Contains(x)).ToList();  
        var table = new Table();
        foreach(var row in remaining1)
        {
            var tableRow = new TableRow();
            foreach (var cell in row.Select(item => new TableCell { Text = item.ToString()}))
            {
                tableRow.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
        }
        Page.Controls.Add(table);
    }
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could simply use 1 cell for the whole `word` in instead of a new cell foreach `letter`

Comment: foreach (var row in remaining1)
            {
                var tableRow = new TableRow();
                tableRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = row.ToString() });                
                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            }

Comment: Why do you use table to display text? Why don't you like the table you output. For me it's expected output. Table of symbols.

Comment: @AccessDenied thanks it works. I tried to display it on label but it didn't work. When i tried using asp gridview or label it gives this "system.collections.generic.list 1 system.string c#". If there is any other way to display could you polk please post it as answer I'd prefer to show it on client side element like asp label or text box or asp gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive list of strings, then you can use literal control:

```
var label = new Literal() { Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough };
label.Text = string.Join("<br />", remaining1);                
Controls.Add(label);
```

If you receive html in body, then you need to escape it:

```
foreach (var line in remaining1)
{
     var label = new Literal() { Mode = LiteralMode.Encode };
     label.Text = line;                
     Controls.Add(label);
     Controls.Add(new Literal(){Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough,Text = "<br />"});
}
```

Comment: both the methods display the strings in the same line until it reaches the end of line then breaks line. I want each string to be displayed on separate line.

Comment: @prkash Second approach adds line breaks.

Comment: Nope using the second method also doesn't break line immediately after the string instead it reached the end of display then breaks line.

Comment: @prkash ok, then try new version. For me it worked even with the oldcode. Make sure you iterate List of strings not response.

Comment: @prkash I modified first method as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll check now. The first one itself works great. Thanks bro :)

Comment: Mind looking at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041889/simplify-if-else-condition-using-timespan-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment92982986_53041889